# dumb-init npm install: No such file or directory when running in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

**dockerfile**

```sh
    FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-buster-slim

    ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]

    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        dumb-init \
        build-essential && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

    ENV HOME=/home/node
    WORKDIR $HOME/app

    COPY --chown=node:node . .

    RUN set -xe && \
        chown -R node /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share /usr/local/bin && \
        npm install && npm cache clean --force

    EXPOSE 4200

    CMD ["node"]
```

**docker-compose**

```sh
    webapp            :
    container_name    : webapp
    hostname          : webapp
    build             :
      dockerfile      : Dockerfile
      context         : ${PWD}/app
    image             : webapp:development
    command           :
                      - npm install
                      - npm run start
    volumes           : 
                      - ${PWD}/webapp:/app
    networks          :
                      - backend
    ports             : 
                      - 4200:4200
    restart           : on-failure
    tty               : true
    stdin_open        : true
    env_file          :
                      - variables.env
```

I can run the image with 
     `docker run webapp bash -c "npm install; npm run start"`
but when I run the compose file it says 
     `webapp  | [dumb-init] npm install: No such file or directory`

I tried to replace the docker-compose command to prefix "node" but the same error but with node npm install: no such file or directory

Can someone tell me where things are going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the list form of `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file (or the JSON-array form of Dockerfile `CMD`) you are providing a list of words in a single command, not a list of separate commands.  Once this gets combined with the `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile, the container command is

```sh
/usr/bin/dumb-init -- 'npm install' 'npm run start'
```

and when there isn't a `/usr/bin/npm\ install` file (including the space in the file name) you get that error.

Since you `COPY` the application code in the Dockerfile and run `npm install` there, you don't need to repeat this step at application start time.  You should be able to delete the `volumes:` and `command:` part of the `docker-compose.yml` file to use what's built in to the image.

If you really need to repeat this `command:`, do it in exactly the form you specified in the `docker run` command, without list syntax

```yaml
command: bash -c 'npm install; npm run start'
```